# NullPointerException in Async JAX-RS implementation

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, nullpointerexception, jax-rs

I am trying to implement Asynchronous JAX-RS. Below is my code:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/isAlive")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public void isAlive(@Suspended AsyncResponse ar) {

        executor.execute(() -> {
            System.out.println("Inside");
            Connection conn = ConnectionUtil.getDBConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt;
            int i = 0;
            try {
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into TEST_TABLE values(?)");
                stmt.setString(1, "TEST INSERT");
                i = stmt.executeUpdate();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ar.resume(i);
       });

    }
```

Upon executing the above code I am getting a Nulpointerexception at `ar.resume(i)`.

```
13:31:35,286 ERROR [stderr] (pool-5-thread-1) Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException

13:31:35,286 ERROR [stderr] (pool-5-thread-1)   at com.test.PublishWSImpl.lambda$0(PublishWSImpl.java:51)

13:31:35,286 ERROR [stderr] (pool-5-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

13:31:35,287 ERROR [stderr] (pool-5-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

What wrong am I doing here? If I remove `ar.resume(i)` part, it is working fine. Why and when should I use the `resume()` method then?

Comment: Which one is the line 51 in PublishWSImpl.java?

Comment: it is ar.resume(i).